# Нормализация чисел с плавающей точкой

Tags: математика, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

В книге Э. Таненбаума «Архитектура компьютера» есть раздел «Приложение Б. Числа с плавающей точкой». Цитата оттуда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не понимаю, как вычисляется число в первом случае, а конкретно, как вычисляется мантисса.

Автор вычисляет мантиссу так: 1×16<sup>-3</sup> + B×16<sup>-4</sup>. Но ведь разряды -3 и -4 заполнены нулями: 0000 и 0000.

По-моему, мантисса равна 0×16<sup>-1</sup> + B×16<sup>-2</sup> + 0×16<sup>-3</sup> + 0×16<sup>-4</sup> = B×16<sup>-2</sup> = 0,04296875<sub>10</sub>. Следовательно, всё число равно +(16<sup>5</sup> × 0,04296875<sub>10</sub>) = +45056<sub>10</sub>. Разве нет?

И еще не понятно, почему для нормализации мы сдвигаем мантиссу на **два** шестнадцатеричных разряда влево. Ведь второй разряд (16<sup>-2</sup>) — ненулевой.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Меня всегда поражала безалаберность издателей и переводчиков, но это какой-то новый уровень. 
[image: Оригинал]